# Windows Phone 8.1: Scan Barcodes using Camera

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8.1, barcode-scanner

I want to scan/read barcodes using camera in Windows Phone 8.1 by **BarcodeScanner** class of the SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.aspx

Is there any example available? How can I use this?

**Edit:**  It seems PointOfService namespace is for Windows but Windows Phone. Is there any similar library available?

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.claimedbarcodescanner.datareceived.aspx

Comment: Thanks Willem but I can't understand (find) CreateDefaultScannerObject() or ClaimScanner() methods. It seems PointOfService namespace is for Windows but Windows Phone. Is that correct?

Comment: My apologies. The MSDN indicates that BarcodeScanner is not supporter on Windows Phone.