# BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync() is always returning null

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to create a simple application in UWP for a Zebra device (Model TC700J) running Windows 8, in which I make use of the built in barcode scanner.

From what I've found, there's plenty of Zebra tutorials for accessing the scanner when programming on Android, but none for Windows due to the fact that Microsoft provide their own generic barcode scanner API found in the **Windows.Devices.PointOfService** namespace.

The code I currently have looks something like this:

```
BarcodeScanner scanner;
ClaimedBarcodeScanner claimedScanner;    

scanner = await BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync();

if (scanner != null)
{
    claimedScanner = await scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();
}
```

The problem is that the if statement never evaluates to true as the **GetDefaultAsync** method always returns null.

[Over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498733/when-is-it-allowable-to-call-barcodescanner-getdefaultasync) there was an answer that seemed to work, stating that it depends where the **GetDefaultAsync** method is placed. I've tried to put it in all of the suggested places though and to no avail.

There is another method, **BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync()** which returns a barcode based on the string representation of that barcode scanner's id sent as a parameter, but I'm not sure that'd be valid here as the barcode scanner is built into the device.

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26498733/7366707)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is related but the solution to that problem was placing the GetDefaultAsync method call in a different location, which isn't working in my particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Zebra's site, TC700J seems to be model number of Windows 10 Mobile IoT Enterprize OS.
And the platform is ARM(Qualcomm snapdragon), not Intel x86/x64.

TC70 / TC75 Touch Computer Series

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld/tc7x-touch-computer-series.html

TC70x Operating System (TC700J) Windows 10 Mobile IoT Enterprise v1.13.02 Release Notes

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/release-notes/operating-system/tc70x-operating-system-v1-13-02--release-notes.html

For example, if your Zebra device is old hardware and Windows Phone 8/8.1 is running, Windows Phone does not seem to support Windows.Devices.PointOfService namespace.

It is described in the comment of the following article.
[Windows Phone 8.1: Scan Barcodes using Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331451/windows-phone-8-1-scan-barcodes-using-camera)

If your Zebra device can update to Windows 10 Mobile IoT Enterprise, please check it after doing it.

If you can update it, you can use the barcode scanner sample for Windows 10.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner

If your device is running on Windows 8 for x86, since Windows.Devices.PointOfService namespace is supported from Windows 8.1, you need to change the OS to Windows 8.1/10 if possible.

In that case you can use following, or above(for Windows10) sample.

Barcode scanner sample for Windows 8.1

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Barcode-scanner-sample-f39aa411

If you can not update it, please get the software and documentation for using BarcodeScanner from the vendor on Windows (Phone?) 8.

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with the operating system and it's compatibility with the PointOfService namespace. Thanks for the very detailed and well-informed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Seems the usage of Async method wasn't quite right.

Try below code:

```
BarcodeScanner scanner;
ClaimedBarcodeScanner claimedScanner;    

scanner = await BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync();

if (scanner != null)
{
    claimedScanner = await scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();
}
```

More details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ah, my apologies, that was actually a typo in my question. But well spotted!