# UWP win 10 mobile barcode scan example for TC70x Zebra

Tags: barcode-scanner

I am looking for a barcode scan example  to be used with the above  windows 10 mobile device . I myself am using visual studio 2017 .  The mobile device ha a build in barcodes scanner but is needs software to function . 
Something like initialize the scanner and put a scanned barcode into a text box would be very helpfull !! 
Thx for any help

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question

Comment: How better can it be ?  i just ask straight away for a code example . I see thousands of  posts asking the same thing

Comment: Please refer to my answer in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712003/barcodescanner-getdefaultasync-is-always-returning-null).

Answer (score 0):

@Robert R,

The version of Windows Mobile used by the Zebra TC70x is Windows Mobile Enterprise which supports the Windows.Devices.PointofService.BarcodeScanner API.  This API is documented at http://aka.ms/pointofservice.  Sample code is available on GitHub, here:  http://aka.ms/PointOfService.SampleApp.BarcodeScanner.

Note: The version of Windows Mobile in the TC70x may not support all functionality that is currently available in the sample.  Please refer to the API reference at http://aka.ms/pointofservice-api details of API availability.  You may need to modify the sample to work on the downlevel version.

Terry Warwick, Microsoft